# Is it worth upgrading my AP Extreme to the new one that supports 802.11ac?

Tags: hardware, airport

I currently have the 802.11n model and all my devices run on 802.11n is there any benefit to the 802.11ac upgrade or should I just wait?

Comment: devices run on .11…. what?  ;-) Assume you mean 11.ac but just wanted to check

Comment: Could you edit this to provide some rationale for what value the upgrade would be? Are you looking to learn if AC works on your hardware or to know something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have devices that use Wireless ac, I would definately upgrade. However, if you do not, don't bother with it.